# In R, how to read a list of filenames into individual data frames?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a (long) list of .csv file names and want to read each .csv file into its own data frame in R.

> ... "./data/2019-Q2.csv"
> "./data/2019-Q3.csv" ...

I thought this should work:

```
allDFs <- lapply(csvPath, read.csv)
```

But it just infinit loops and I have to manually stop it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use `list.files` and get all the .csv file paths i.e. `files <- list.files(pattern = "/data/2019-.*\\.csv$", all.names = TRUE); lapply(files, read.csv)`

Comment: Yes, I have the list of file names (from using list.files) in a previous step. But how do I go from the list.files to getting each file read into its own data frame?

Comment: you can use `lst1 <- lapply(files, read.csv)` it loops through each element and reads the dataset with read.csv

Comment: Seems unlikely that you could get an infinite loop. How many files exactly do you have? Do you have enough RAM to load all the data into memory?

Comment: Try `allDFs <- lapply(head(csvPath), read.csv)` which will just read the first 6 files. Then look at `allDFs`. It should be a list with 6 parts, `allDFs[[1]]` is the first data frame, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in the data using `list.files` and `lapply`, as suggested in the OP comments. To make each list item a separate data frame, use the `assign()` function in a for loop:

```
d <- split(iris, f = iris$Species)

for (i in names(d)) {
  assign(i, d[[i]])
}
```

This uses the list names as the newly assigned variable name, so make sure this is set appropriately.